# How can I get two addresses from the API at the same time?

Tags: android, api, rest

I have the following situation: the user enters the latitude and longitude of two points. I would like to get the addresses of these points at the same time, but I have no idea how I can do it. Currently, I only get the address of one point, this is my code:

```
public class RemoteRepository {
    private ApiRequest apiRequest;

    public RemoteRepository() {
        apiRequest = RetrofitRequest.getInstance().create(ApiRequest.class);
    }

    public LiveData<AddressResponse> getAddress(double query1, double query2) {
        final MutableLiveData<AddressResponse> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        apiRequest.getAddress(query1, query2)
                .enqueue(new Callback<AddressResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AddressResponse> call, Response<AddressResponse> response) {

                        if(response.body() != null) {
                            data.setValue(response.body());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AddressResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        data.setValue(null);
                    }
                });

        return data;
    }
}
```

How can I get the addresses of two points at the same time? Should I implement the recall call below:

```
apiRequest.getAddress(query1, query2)
```

Comment: Your API must accept 2 points at the same time and response 2 address at the same time as a list of `AddressResponse`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 Points consider to change signature on `getAddress(double query1, double query2)` to `getAddress(MyPoint point1, MyPoint point2` then return 2 address from your service.

```java
public class MyPoint{
 public double x;
 public double y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that your API must accept the two points at the same time and return 2 addresses from your API as a list.

Change your request as below:

First, create the class AddressPoint in your project:

```
public class AddressPoint{
 public double x;
 public double y;

public AddressPoint(double x,double y){
this.x= x;
this.y= y;
}

}
```

Then call your request as below:

```
AddressPoint query1 = AddressPoint(point1,point2);  // point1,point2,point3,point4 of type double
AddressPoint query2 = AddressPoint(point3,point4);

apiRequest.getAddress(query1, query2);
```

To receive two address from the backend/API your Json should be like this:

```
{
  "addresses": [
    "Address1",
    "Address2"
  ]
}
```

And your AddressResponse class should be like this:

```
public class AddressResponse {

@SerializedName("addresses")
@Expose
private List<String> addresses = null;

public List<String> getAddresses() {
return addresses;
}

public void setAddresses(List<String> addresses) {
this.addresses = addresses;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm using this API: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/ and 
I do not see the possibility of obtaining addresses in the mentioned format by you. This is my query: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987

Comment: @mikoxy You can achieve this with the API you are using, please see the API documentation.